# Ajax Postback - Render full view once again

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using **Ajax.BeginForm()** and a **UpdateTargetId**. However when the user has successfully completed the form and I have done the processing I want to redirect them to a brand new page.

Calling RedirectToAction() and returning a view from there does not work as it targets the id.

I also need to pass parameters to the action. So is my only option to make a JavaScript call of:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'http://www.somewhere.com/blah/blah?aMyParam=123'");
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If you want to redirect, why are you using `Ajax.BeginForm()`? (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page) - why not submit a standard form?

Comment: @Stephen Because while I am validating I want to do a partial update without a full postback. The reason for this is that the form is part of other "areas" on the page which are "heavy" when retrieved from the databse so performing a full page refresh each time validation fails is not great for UX.

Answer (score 1):

Although the way you are doing is correct but more elegant way to do this is shown below :-

Controller -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    if (model.SomeCondition)
    {
        // return to the client the url to redirect to
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("MyAction2") });
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_MyPartialView");
    }
}
```

View -

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "foo" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Javascript -

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
    if (result.url) {
        window.location.href = result.url;
    }
}
```

As shown above you can return `Json`(having url) from controller action and then redirect from `onSuccess` javascript function.